# A basic doubt on the difference/relation of limit point of a set and limit of a sequence

Tags: real-analysis

If a convergent sequence $\{x_n\}$ does not have a constant subsequence, then the "limit" $x$ of $\{x_n\}$ becomes a "limit point" of the range set of  $\{x_n\}$.

Is the above statement true ?

Answer (score 0):

We are assuming that the sequence $(x_n)$ has limit $x$. If the sequence $(x_n)$ contains no infinite constant subsequence, then every neighbourhood of $x$ contains a point in the range which is not equal to $x$. Thus $x$ is a limit point of the range set.

We don't even need the condition that the sequence $(x_n)$ contains no constant infinite subsequence. All we need is that the are arbitrarily large $n$ such that $x_n\ne x$.

Comment: Nicolas : understood.